# How to create Maximum azure VMs using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Could you please help me with some powershell to provision multiple VMs (Linux) PARALLEL.

What is Max VM count ,we can create in one subscription.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many VMs as you want till your resources are not exhausted (I believe you are not asking for the approach how you are going to create the VMs)There is a limit/constraint for - fixed no of VMs in a cloud service OR fixed number of vhds in a storage account OR fixed number of IPs in subnet/vNet etc

It totally depends on your strategy and un-used resources left in your subscription.

Comment: Could you also suggets. How can provision Linux Multi VMs using Powershell

Comment: May I know which approach you are planning - ASM or ARM ?

Comment: i am looking for ARM Method